# How to get the match index in the string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

how can i get the index of matching pattern in the string using javascript?

consider string original_string = "i am [1@some user] some more text [2@another user]"

i am using pattern /[\d+@(?[^]\r\n]*)]/g to match strings in square brackets

then i use string.matchAll(original_string) to get the matches

```
const matches = string.matchAll(original_string);
let names = [];
for (const match in matches) {
    names.push(match);
 }

 now the names array will contain ["some user", "another user"]
 now how do i get the index of the first match in original string from names array.

  const final_string = []
  const original_string = "i am [12@some user] some text [2@some user2]"
  let prev_match_pos = 0
  for each match in original_string 
      final_string.push(text from the end of prev match up until current 
      match start)
      final_string.push(<span>match</span>)
      update prev_match_pos

  final_string.push(text from the end of previous match to the end of the 
  original string)
```

I want to implement the above algorithm in javascript.

Basically i want to convert this string "i am [1@some user] some more text [2@another user]"

to

"i am `<span>some user</span>` some more text `another user'"

how can i do it?

the basic implementation is as below,

get the strings in brackets.
from the string in brackets extract value after @ character.
then embed the extracted value in span tag and place them in the original string.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Please first try it yourself. Once you've tried it and have hit a problem, please post another question on SO with the specific problem you are having

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have explained where i am encountering problem. after finding matches i dont know how to replace them in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the `[id@name]` portion with the formatted name (e.g. `<span>name</span>`), you can use **String.replace**.

```
const text = 'i am [1@some user] some more text [2@another user]';
text.replace(/\[\d+@([A-z\s]*)\]/g, '<span>$1</span>');
// outputs: i am <span>some user</span> some more text <span>another user</span>
```

[`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) supports using **capture groups** in the `newSubstr` parameter (new substring).

Comment: Looks like you've changed something in the regex. Can you explain why were these changes needed? The approach seems like a nice one.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I forgot about that. I had to escape both brackets because we need to match them literally. I could not make my browser accept the original regex, and I am not familiar with the `?` and negating a match `^`, so I assumed text with spaces (`[A-z\s]+`) would suffice. Symbols and numbers could be added as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to improve the regex, this works well to for the given example,

```
let originalString = "i am [1@some user] some more text [2@another user]";

const matches = originalString.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
let newString = originalString;
matches.forEach(match => {
  newString = newString.replace(
    `[${match}]`,
    `<span>${match.split("@")[1]}</span>`
  );
});
console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

don't really know if this can help you but a quick solution could be:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>user 1 : <span id="first"></span></p>
  <p>user 2: <span id="second"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
let string = "first user is [1@user1] and second is [2@user2]";

let users = string.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g).map(el => el.split('@')[1]);

document.getElementById('first').innerText = users[0];
document.getElementById('second').innerText = users[1];
</script>
```